# How to split on whitespaces in Ocaml?

Tags: regex, string, ocaml

A white space is either a space, tab, or newline character (i.e., carriage return or line feed)

I'm assuming that `\s` covers , `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, and `\f`

But when I've tried using `\s` it fails to split the string properly:

```
# let line1 = "We the People of the United States, in Order to form a more perfect";;

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "\\s+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list = 
["We the People of the United State"; ", in Order to form a more perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ \\s]+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list = 
["We"; "the"; "People"; "of"; "the"; "United"; "State"; ","; "in"; "Order"; "to"; "form"; "a"; "more"; "perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[\\s]+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list = 
["We the People of the United State"; ", in Order to form a more perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ \\s\\t\\n\\r]+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We"; "he"; "People"; "of"; "he"; "U"; "i"; "ed"; "S"; "a"; "e"; ","; "i"; "O"; "de"; "o"; "fo"; "m"; "a"; "mo"; "e"; "pe"; "fec"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[\s]+";;
Characters 29-31:                                                               
Warning 14: illegal backslash escape in string.                                 
val wsp_regex : Str.regexp = <abstr>   

# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We the People of the United State"; ", in Order to form a more perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ \s]+";;
Characters 30-32:                                                               
Warning 14: illegal backslash escape in string.                                 
val wsp_regex : Str.regexp = <abstr>
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We"; "the"; "People"; "of"; "the"; "United"; "State"; ","; "in"; "Order"; "to"; "form"; "a"; "more"; "perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ \t\n\r\f]+";;
Characters 36-38:                                                               
Warning 14: illegal backslash escape in string.                                 
val wsp_regex : Str.regexp = <abstr>  
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We"; "the"; "People"; "o"; "the"; "United"; "States,"; "in"; "Order"; "to"; "orm"; "a"; "more"; "per"; "ect"] 

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[\t\n\r\f]+";;
Characters 35-37:                                                               
Warning 14: illegal backslash escape in string.                                 
val wsp_regex : Str.regexp = <abstr>
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We the People o"; " the United States, in Order to "; "orm a more per"; "ect"]
```

The only cases that seem to be working are:

```
# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ ]+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We"; "the"; "People"; "of"; "the"; "United"; "States,"; "in"; "Order"; "to"; "form"; "a"; "more"; "perfect"]

# let wsp_regex = Str.regexp "[ \t\n\r]+";;
# let words = Str.split wsp_regex line1;;
val words : string list =                                                         
["We"; "the"; "People"; "of"; "the"; "United"; "States,"; "in"; "Order"; "to"; "form"; "a"; "more"; "perfect"]
```

I'm not sure why the second case works because doing `[ \s]+` hasn't work (Ocaml thinks I want to split on a  or a `s`)

All I want is to split on the whitespace without using just  because I also want to capture `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, and `\f`.

However I can't seem to figure out how to create a regex expression in Ocaml to split on white spaces.

If someone could provide me a working expression that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the documentation of the [`Str` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Str.html) you'll find that `\s` is not supported. So your first expression is going to separate words on sequences of the character `s`. Which is what you see, in fact.

None of the other attempts with `\s` is going to work, since `\s` isn't supported.

Surprisingly, even `\n` (the two-character notation) isn't supported as a regular expression. So if you want to match a newline, you need an actual newline in your regular expression pattern. In other words, you want the string to have this: `"\n"`, not this: `"\\n"`. The same is true for `\r` and `\t`.

The notation `\f` isn't accepted by the OCaml string syntax. If you want to match a form-feed you need to use its hexadecimal notation `\x0c`.

Putting this all together, your pattern should be this: `"[ \n\r\x0c\t]+"`.

```
# Str.split (Str.regexp "[ \n\r\x0c\t]+") line1;;
- : string list =
["We"; "the"; "People"; "of"; "the"; "United"; "States,"; "in";
 "Order"; "to"; "form"; "a"; "more"; "perfect"]
```

There is a Perl-Compatible Regular Expression package, which you might find more comfortable to use: https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/pcre/pcre.7.1.5/

Comment: thanks you!!! I was so befuddled as to why this wasn't working, I appreciate you're help :)